# How to make the transition to a view controller with a navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have two modules that I need to connect.

1. The authorization module, which consists of 1 screen. There is no
   controller Navigation on it and it is not in its stack.
2. Main application. The first screen is the root for the controller
   navigation.

How can I implement the transition in case of successful authorization from the authorization screen to the main application in Swift code?

[My screen scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpano.png)

## **SOLUTION:**

I use this solution for my case:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "rootVC")
        UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController = vc
        view.present(vc, animated: true) {
            self.view.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give storyboardId "nav" to the Navigation Controller and then present it on your login view controller.

```
if let nav = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nav") {
    self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: In this case, the previously created Login View Controller will not remain exist?

Answer (score 0):

on your navigation Controller on storyboard add your storyboard Id, for example I have named it as `navController`

[image]

In your code, from you want to show as the navigation controller as present, add this line

case if presented view Controller on **same storyboard**

```
if let navController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navController") {
    self.present(navController, animated : true, completion : nil)
}
```

case if presented view controller on **different storyboard**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name : STORYBOARD_NAME, bundle : nil)
let nav = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navController")
self.present(navController, animated : true, completion : nil)
```